# How can I return anything if the id don't match after sending a command?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

at first sorry by my bad english again, perhaps the title doesn't match to my question, so if anyone want to change i wourld thank! ^^
Well, I'll try to explain as best I can with my English from day care and google translate..

I have a list of people in my database, and to get it I use explode, I'm creating a command to get the id of each user in this list for example list:

```
LewBr,GenericGamerOeg,LywBr,Server
```

---

### What i receive on explode

So, if i use explode and i get this at var_dump =

`array(4) {
[0]=>
string(5) "LewBr"
[1]=>
string(15) "GenericGamerOeG"
[2]=>
string(5) "LywBr"
[3]=>
string(6) "Server"
}`

---

### The command

args are the command if i set example of this code i'm getting when i do this:

> /test 2

and for example 2 is the ID of the array like if i do /test 2 i will get LywBr, if i do /test 1 i will get LewBr, /test 3 i will get Server and etc..

```
         if(strtolower($args[0]) == "test") {
            $str = $this->plugin->getDataGeral($user->getName())["list"];
            $a = explode(',',$str);
                        if($a[$args[1]]){
                        $user->sendMessage("You are getting ".$a[$args[1]]."");
                        return true;  
                    }

        }
```

---

### Matriz/GetDataGeral

```
 public function getDataGeral($player){
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `nome`, `list` WHERE `nome` = ?");
$stmt_player = strtolower($player);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $stmt_player);
if($stmt->execute()){
                    $stmt->bind_result($nome, $list);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $data = array(
                        "nome" => $nome,
                        "list" => $list
                    );
                    $stmt->close();
                    return $data;
                }else{
                    $stmt->close();
                }
}
```

---

### What i'm trying to do..

I am trying to return and send a message to that user if the id does not exist.. example if the user try to set

> /test 4,5,6,7

I need to do an event that if i do /test 4,5,6 etc... that does not exist i need that that returns and send a message to the sender that the player don't exist..  AGAIN SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH!

Comment: It sounds like your DB is not designed well. I would correct that rather than doing this work around.

Comment: It is, why should not?

Comment: You should just be able to select the name from the `id`.

Comment: I can do that, you don't understood what i need to do.. I need to do an event that if i do /test 4,5,6 etc... that does not exist i need that that returns and send a message to the sender that the player don't exist.. Understand?

Comment: Agree with @chris85 that your database doesn't seem to be designed properly. This is because you should have all the users separately and not in one field. In case you have your database designed properly, then you might be retrieving the data incorrectly. Please share your DB along with the code from which you are getting your array.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi But i need to get in only one column.. '-'

Comment: That is what @chris85 and myself are trying to explain. There is some serious database design issue. Every industry follows some standards as the experts in the past and present have experienced and came up with these standards. You can easily have all the data in one Variable/Array/HTML Output very easily even if they are stored separately. Therefore saving them in one cell is never recommended.

Comment: Ok, i have updated my question look it now.. And why really is not recommended?

Comment: As an advice, create a separate table `list` and store your data there. Have a reference field that binds both the tables, i.e. `list` and `other_table`. This can be an ID. You can easily your `INNER JOIN` or other such methods to retrieve specific data.

Comment: Just to give you a very quick example to prove that why it is not recommended. Image I have a table that stores an Invoice. So all the Items in the Invoice vary from Invoice to Invoice. Some may have 3 items and some even more. No limit to it. So imaging all the items of an invoice in one cell. Now you are actually overloading the database in every query. Search is also not easy, both for you and the DB. This is just to give you an idea.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered in its current form. But to help you out, I would like to mention that in case you have `list` table maintained separately, it would be very easy to look for the ID. If the ID is not found, intimate the user.

Comment: By the way, as per your database structure where the entire list is stored in one cell, just imaging if one entry is deleted by mistake, your entire list is gone. Consider revising your database structure. @chris85 is spot on in pointing out this.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi I am trying to do in one column because i have too many users for example, and if i set table by table my database can be very big in bytes.. But in one string column it's not soo a bad idea or it is very much better in other tables?

Comment: You don't have to set tables for each user. You just have to have one separate table with all the users as entries.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi I have already tryed to do that but i have a problem by getting all users of the 2° table of an specific user..

Comment: Then post your efforts here as a question. To understand the logic better, explore StackExchange as there are specific websites for advise on choices as well. I cannot remember right now but you can find. Stackoverflow is not for seeking such advises. It is to help solve coding issues.